# How to create an Inner Shadow effect using Expression Blend

Tags: expression-blend, shadow

I'm aware of the DropShadowEffect using blend, but I need the shadow to appear on the inside of the control giving it an internal recessed appearance.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

here is a technique that uses a drop shadow with a clipping path to trim the outside edge leaving only the inner portion of the shadow

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/innershadows.aspx

Comment: Thankk you for the link, this helped greatly!